# Regex expression only matching the first occurrance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, hashtag

I'm trying to match all @mentions and #hashtags on a String using this RegEx expression:

```
(^|\s)([#@][a-z\d-]+)
```

According to regex101.com, since the + is there it should match all occurances

> "+" Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

But when I run it through a String with more than one occurrance, it only matches the first.

What's going on?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: You will need to use global identifier. `/(^|\s)([#@][a-z\d-]+)/g`

Comment: @StéphaneAmmar javascript tag is there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `g` (global) flag at the end for multiple matches.

```
/(^|\s)([#@][a-z\d-]+)/g
```

Comment: Correct, I had seen it being mentioned in older issues but I didn't understand where to put it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`^` this symbol defines beginning of string. That is why it only match with first string.

Use `/[@#]\w+/` regex.

Comment: Totally wrong. ```(^|\s)``` means *space* **or** *beginning*

Comment: I mentioned only ^ symbol not \s.